# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker

Tags: angular, typescript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular7

We have a PWA that has been working fine for a long time, but now it seems the app is having trouble registering the service worker. We are using Angular 7 and the `ngsw-worker.js` is not output in the build folder. The error in the console is:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.

We are registering the service worker in `core.module.ts` like this:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
```

Our ngsw-config.json look like this:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is the `ngsw-worker.js` file supposed to be output explicitly in the dist folder, or is it part of the bundle?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12665#issuecomment-439923077 suggests that this is an issue with Angular's dependencies.

Comment: That post solved my issue, thanks @JeffPosnick